# WiFI issues on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with 4.9 kernel and Atheros AR9285 PCI wireless adapter

Tags: kernel, wifi, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

UPDATE

After some time we got around to testing it with a 5.4 kernel under Ubuntu 20.04. Same issue, setting up the network using`nmcli` is easy, but there is still no SSID to be found. Although we have decided to move on using a different manufacturer, it would still be nice to know why it is failing.

ETADPU

We have some (embedded) systems based on the NXP i.MX6Q boards. Some are equipped with Intel WiFi modules and some are equipped with modules based on the Atheros AR9285 chipset.

We have for a while been running Ubuntu 14.04 with a 3.14 kernel, and the Atheros modules works fine with that setup. We now want to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, and from the producer of the board we obtained a 4.9 kernel, which we have configured and built.

With this kernel, systems equipped with the Intel module can establish wifi connections, and using hostapd, can be configured as hotspots, which is what we want. Systems with the Atheros modules cannot.

Things that work:

- `lshw -c network` shows the network
- `lspci` shows the chip is connected
- Using `ip`, the interface can be changed
- configuring static IP through `/etc/network/interfaces` brings the interface up correctly
- Running the `hostapd` daemon using `systemctl` does not fail.
- the `nohwcrypt` flag is set for the chip
- There's a basic "use NetworkManager" configuration in the netplan .yaml file
- Using same disk on a system with Intel chip works -> setup works
- Using 14.04 setup on same hardware works -> hardware works

Basicly, everything feels like it *should* be working, but the accesspoint doesn't show up, and it cannot be connected to a wifi network.

In my view, it is a problem specificly tied to the Atheros chip. I am in now way an expert on kernel configurations, and my google abilities has yet to reveal a working solution. So any help would be appreciated!